# Create Mylyn tasks through java code

Tags: mylyn

I want to create Mylyn tasks through code. I searched for Mylyn javadoc but could not find anything relevant. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of these (I found it via `NewTaskAction`)

```
TasksUiUtil.openNewLocalTaskEditor(shell, null);

TasksUiUtil.openNewTaskEditor(shell, null, TasksUiUtil.getSelectedRepository());

TasksUiUtil.openNewTaskEditor(shell, null, null);
```

`TasksUiUtil` is in `org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui` package, this is public API. Mylyn doesn't have very good Javadocs :-(